# How to pass an ember object to handlebars helper

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

I want to pass an ember object to the handlebars helper, I used the helper as shown below but it is not receiving correct object. It is just printing the name of the object in console see the code below

```
//ember helper
Ember.Handlebars.registerHelper('act', function (value) {
            console.log(value); //It prints as item.label               
            return value+"1";
        }); 

//template
     {{#each item in content}}
                <li ><a {{bindAttr href="item.link"}}>{{act item.label}}</a></li>
                {{/each}}



 // Ember model which i am using


  App.AllRoutes = [Ember.Object.create({                
            label: "index",
            link:"#/",

        }),
  Ember.Object.create({
            label: "second",                
            link: "#/second",                
        }),
```

**Update**
Even though srinivasan solution works It doesn't work for problem shown below. registerBoundHelper return the value with script elements. So for  It cannot be used inside tags. Any other help ?

```
//ember helper
Ember.Handlebars.registerBoundHelper('act', function (value) {
            console.log(value); //It prints as item.label 
          if (value == "somevalue"){ return  new Handlebars.SafeString("class='active'"); }

        }); 

//template
     {{#each item in content}}
                <li {{act item.label}} ><a {{bindAttr href="item.link"}}>{{label}}</a></li>
                {{/each}}
```

I am using 
Ember.VERSION : 1.0.0-rc.7,
Handlebars.VERSION : 1.0.0

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand your question. You're passing `item.label` into the helper, but you expect to get the item as an argument? Why not just do `{{act item}}`?

Also, why are you trying to emulate the `{{#linkTo}}` helper that [already exists](http://emberjs.com/guides/templates/links/) in Ember?

Comment: 'item' is an object it contains link and label properties that's why I am passing item.label property. see the helper it is returning the received property plus adding some extra string. Even I tried to pass the item object same issue. However if 'this' property is passed console prints nothing but no error. I just want to add active class to the list item according to the route rendered. In {{#linkTo}} it's not possible to bind the route, so I am emulating it.

Comment: You can add an active class using `#linkTo`, you just have to use two of them. https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/pull/1849

Answer (score 0):

Kindly check the following.

JAVASCRIPT:

```
App=Em.Application.create({});

App.Router.map(function(){
    this.route('all');
    this.route('index');
    this.route('second');          
});

Ember.Handlebars.registerBoundHelper('act', function (value) {              
        return value+"1";
    }); 

App.IndexRoute=Em.Route.extend({
    redirect:function(){this.transitionTo('all');}
});

App.AllRoute =Em.Route.extend({
    model:function(){
        return  [Ember.Object.create({                
        label: "index",
        link:"#/"
    }),
      Ember.Object.create({
        label: "second",                
        link: "#/second"                
    })];
 }
});
```

HTML

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" >
    {{outlet}}
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="all">
           {{#each item in controller}}
                <li ><a {{bindAttr href="item.link"}}>{{act item.label}}</a></li>
                {{/each}}


</script>
```